# change metadata tag before importing mp4 into iTunes to Music Video

Tags: itunes, video, music, mp4

I am a DJ and use record pools to download music and music videos. This is a legal source of mp3 and mp4 of music singles remixed/edited from the album version.

My current workflow is:

1. Hazel will find mp3s that have not been matched before, open in Metadatics app and add a color tag.
2. Keyboard maestro when it detects Metadatics is open and execute macros emulating keystrokes to `select all` then `strip all artwork` then `save all` and finally `quit` metadatics.
3. Hazel will search for mp3s with color tag that are more than 30 minutes old and import into iTunes.

I want to run a similar workflow with mp4 that will

1. match mp4s that `contain` source/URL of the record pool URL.
2. strip artwork
3. **change metadata so mp4 is imported as `Music Video`**

TL;DR 
what is the metadata tag to make a mp4 imported into iTunes as Music Video?

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, music videos have the following metadata:

- **genre:** Music Video
- **media kind** Music Video
- **kind** Purchased MPEG-4 video file

As a minimum, I imagine you'd have to change the `genre` and `media kind` metadata so that they're labelled as `Music Video` to ensure the .mp4 files are imported as music videos.

As an aside, you can typically view the above metadata within iTunes by doing a Get Info. That is, select the item and press <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> (or you can go to iTunes > Edit > Get Info). This brings up all the metadata and you can view the:

- **genre** within the **Details** tab
- **media kind** within the **Options** tab
- **kind** within the **File** tab

Comment: yes, I know I can change/edit the MP4 file directly in iTunes. However, I would like to change the metadata so that it imports into iTunes directly as a `Music Video`. not having to manually change each or a group of `Home Videos`

Comment: Yep, I understood what you wanted to do with your workflow. What I meant by my answer was that the metadata you'd need to change, as a minimum, is the `genre` and `media kind` and that you'd need to change these to `Music Video` so that the .mp4 files are imported as music videos. I've updated my answer to clarify this.  If I've misunderstood your question altogether, let me know.